# Unable to create shipment programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9, shipment, shipment-tracking

I try to create programmatically a shipment of an order with a track code.
This is my current code :

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId("100014930");
$shipment = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareShipment($order->getItemQtys());

$arrTracking = array(
                'carrier_code' => $order->getShippingCarrier()->getCarrierCode(),
                'title' => $order->getShippingCarrier()->getConfigData('title'),
                'number' => "1234",
            );

$track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')->addData($arrTracking);
$shipment->addTrack($track);

$shipment->register();
$order->save();
```

With this, I have no error while I execute it.
In the Magento panel, you can't ship the order, but the order stay in pending and the shipment doesn't appear.
Please help

Problem solved with this [solution](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/54840/not-able-to-create-shipment-programmatically)

Comment: Without any errors is hard to help you. Check all logs, also if logging is on and make sure display_errors is enabled

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found your error. `getItemQtys` is not a valid function on any Magento class, so in Magento magic methods it returns `null`. Essentially you're trying to ship `null` number of items. You can't do that. Yes, it fails silently.

Some controllers implement a `_getItemQtys` method to return the values you're looking for; however none of these are plug and play. Instead I suggest you create this as it's just a keyed array in the format of:

```
array(
  'order_item_id'=>$qty,
  'order_item_id'=>$qty,
  'order_item_id'=>$qty
)
```

However, if you're always shipping all items in a shipment, without exception there is an even easier way:

```
$converter=Mage::getModel('sales/convert_order');
$shipment=$converter->toShipment($order);
```

Please read this answer here for more information on how to create shipments programmatically:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/3345/336

Comment: I replaced the getItemsQty line with converter.  
When I execute, I got a Mage_Core_Exception "Cannot create an empty shipment" but when I var_dump the shipment (juste before saving it) I have all the information about it.
Is it because loading the order like I did does make a Varien Object ?

Comment: You needn't do anything (including save) just create the shipment with the $order.

Comment: So i don't keep the line with $shipment->register() ?
Do i keep the addTrack() things ?
Now just nothing is happening, no error, no shipment created.